# Caffe - Python quit unexpectedly while using the libglog.0.dylib plug-in

Tags: python, python-2.7, deep-learning, caffe, glog

I am trying to **run the [deep visualization toolbox](https://github.com/yosinski/deep-visualization-toolbox) using Caffe**

Specs:

- Mac OS X 10.10
- Python2.7
- `import caffe` works fine

when I try to run `./run_toolbox.py` I get the alert:

> Python quit unexpectedly while using the libglog.0.dylib plug-in

Console Output:

> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>   [1](https://github.com/yosinski/deep-visualization-toolbox)    39095 abort      ./run_toolbox.py

`brew reinstall glog` did not work and I don´t know where to beginn.

Answer (score 0):

Error resolved in settings_local.py

`# Use GPU? Default is True.`
Change to `False` if no GPU used or no dependencies installed.

```
caffevis_mode_gpu = False
```

Mac: I also recommend installing all Python packages in a virtualenv, and all non-Python packages via brew.